# How does make tell when a file hasn't been modified?

Tags: makefile

Make can tell if a file has been modified since the last `make` invocation. I guess it compares the files' modification times with the time they were last built. To do this it would have to store the latest times on disk, right?

Anyone know if and where or how it does that?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `stat` the unix commandline program. File records ecord mtimes intrinsically. make just checks those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do that.

Instead, it compares the modification time of the target with the modification times of its dependencies.  So when you have a rule

```
foo-sorted: foo; sort $< > $@
```

the modification times of `foo-sorted` and `foo` are compared.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you didn't look too hard to find an answer:

> http://www.gnu.org/software/make/ If a target file is newer than all of its dependencies, then it is already up to date, and it does not need to be regenerated.
>
> http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html The criterion for being out of date is specified in terms of the *prerequisites*, which consist of file names separated by spaces. [...] A target is out of date if it does not exist or if it is older than any of the prerequisites (by comparison of last-modification times). The idea is that the contents of the target file are computed based on information in the prerequisites, so if any of the prerequisites changes, the contents of the existing target file are no longer necessarily valid.
>
> http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html The *make* utility examines time relationships and shall update those derived files (called targets) that have modified times earlier than the modified times of the files (called prerequisites) from which they are derived.